# How do i toggle the 'No option text' of MUI Autocomplete? toggle text based on if/else conditions

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

I'm trying to toggle **noOptionText**. MUI Autocomplete component provides this property for selecting searched text/value from multiple option. if there is no option available then **noOptionText** will shows it's value.

```
 <Autocomplete
                 noOptionsText='Data not found'
 />
```

i wanna toggle this text using if/else condition as below:

```
 <Autocomplete
                        noOptionsText={
                          true
                            ? 'Location not found'
                            : 'Type atleast 4 letters'
                        }
 />
```